# The Random 666 number.

Tags: random-variables, random

Does the number 666 more likely to come up more than other numbers like 777?
The register, on stock exchange and at the pump?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuOr4.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiSAH.jpg)

Comment: Yes!  666 comes up more often than 777 (and less often than 555) in many situations due to [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).

Comment: @vadim123 can i use this as my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something known as [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) that says under certain circumstances, numbers with smaller leading digits are more common. This includes a cash register, stock prices, and gas pump numbers as long as your units are small enough. We usually measure human height in feet or meters. In both cases, it's impossible for a number to start with a $9$. The "small enough units" requirement is to check to make sure that such factors are insignificant, and all you need is that the range of values "wraps" around multiple times in the sense that there are entries of many different lengths of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! 666 comes up more often than 777 (and less often than 555) in many situations due to Benford's law. – vadim123